Dpi-1080 connection was closed by ORA-41409
I am getting below when I am running the application, if you restart the node app error will not come, and everything works fine, this error occurs only few times. Dpi-1080 connection was closed by  ORA-41409.
Poolsize: min: 2 max: 18.
I am using node js, knex, and Oracle.
Versions:
Node: 16.20.0
Knex: "^2.4.2"
Oracledb: "^5.1.0"
I should not get any connection related issues and application should work fine
Is there any configuration for this?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Is there any configuration for database setup for knex to avoid the error connection closed by ORA-41409

process.on('SIGINT',  async () => { await db. Knex.destroy(); process.exit(0): })

process.on('SIGTERM',  async () => { await db. Knex.destroy(); process.exit(0): })
